# How can I prevent Solr from adding headers and footers?

Tags: c#-4.0, solr, web-crawler

I have a webcrawler([Ncrawler](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/)) that crawls a website content and I have added code to index the data to solr. My requirement is to avoid the headers, footers and navigation pane of the website from adding to solr for indexing.

Is there any way to do this? Any help will be really grateful.

Thanks,
Anu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `HtmlDocumentProcessor` class that has a filterTextRules parameter on the constructor. This parameter needs to be passed as a `Dictionary<string,string>` with the start and end strings to use for filtering the markup.

As an example, let say that you have a header and footer in your html pages and they are structured as follows in the html:

```
 <!-- Begin Header -->
 all header markup is here
 <!-- End Header -->

 <!-- Begin Footer -->
 all footer markup is here
 <!-- End Footer -->
```

In this case you can initialize the HtmlDocumentProcessor in your pipeline as follows:

```
    var pipelines = new IPipelineStep[]
               {
                  new HtmlDocumentProcessor(
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                               {"<!--Begin Header", "<!--End Header"},
                               {"<!--Begin Footer", "<!--End Footer"},
                            }, 
                            null), 
                         new PdfIFilterProcessor(), 
                         new TextDocumentProcessor(), 
                };

    using (var crawler = new NCrawler.Crawler(new Uri("http://ncrawler.codeplex.com"),
             pipelines))
    {
          //Processing here
    }
```

Hope that this helps. For more details on the filterTextRules parameter and how it works please see the [HtmlDocumentProcessor source](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/79962#758237).

Comment: Thank you Thank you so much... :) @Paige Cook. Your answers really really helps me...not only in this question, but in the last ones also. Is there any reference links or ebooks for ncrawler-solr integration that are worth reading?

Comment: Glad that these have been helpful. Unfortunately, there is not any NCrawler-Solr Integration references, I have learned all of this through trial and error.